# xmpp presence not receiving in delegate methods using iOS and Swift 3

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using Mongoose. I'm on Ubuntu server and Swift 3 in client side. I am not able to get the user's presence in delegate function. I have implemented code like this for Subscripting presence, this is not calling

```
func xmppRoster(_ sender: XMPPRoster!, didReceivePresenceSubscriptionRequest presence: XMPPPresence!) {
        debugPrint("XMPPRoster : didReceivePresenceSubscriptionRequest ")
        debugPrint(presence)
        sender.acceptPresenceSubscriptionRequest(from: presence.from(), andAddToRoster: true)
    }
```

also when user is sending presence I am not able to get presence of user in this delegate method :

```
func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream!, didReceivePresence presence: XMPPPresence!) {
        debugPrint(presence)

    }
```

Please let me know where I am getting wrong.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in guessing the correct conversion of method declarations from Objective-C to Swift.  The following declaration of XMPPFramework callback works in Swift 4:

```
@objc func xmppStream(_ stream:XMPPStream, didReceivePresence presence:XMPPPresence) {
    print("\(presence)")
}
```